# Left and Right region is not showing on ZEN sub theme

Tags: theming

I've been working right now on a custom sub theme via ZEN for a certain Drupal site. I had it first developed in my localhost. Right after I had the half of the basic design implemented, I uploaded it immediately to the site and had it enabled. Now, something is wrong. The two regions are not showing up when I tried to view them on the block administration page. Even if I put a block on each of them, still they don't display on the page... what could it be?

In my localhost, it's working fine. I'm not sure why it's not working well on the live site. Has anyone of you experienced the same issue? Any help or suggestion is very much appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you clear the theme cache?

Comment: yes.. many times already.. I also had it disabled and enabled again. Further actions I did was to disable, and remove the theme and re upload it again.. still the result is the same T_T

Comment: i found the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this problem. That is the put 'zen' folder under the same location of the sub-theme folder. Actually, the site I've been working on is a multi site setup and there is also an entity there that is also using zen as it's theme. I thought putting just my sub-theme is enough since the site still recognized the main theme, which is Zen.

The reason why the two region of the theme I uploaded is not being recognized, is because it's info file is not being read properly. The info file that is being read by the site is found, on the other zen sub-theme I mentioned above.